# Line-height у inline-элемента в Firefox

Tags: firefox, css

Проблема в том, что inline-элемент в Firefox и IE9 (Chrome, Opera, IE7-8 нормально работают) не меняет свой line-height, если внешнему тегу  задан свой line-height. Кто-нибудь знает, как это обойти?

Comment: Прежде чем задавать такой вопрос вы хотя бы попробовали поискать ответ на него например в гугле?...сомневаюсь...вот тут например можешь почитать http://habrahabr.ru/blogs/css/117109/

Comment: Прежде чем писать "гугл в помощь" можно и глянуть, что у меня проблема не с inline-block, а с inline - это разные вещи. И, предвещая Ваш вопрос, я не могу прописать inline-block.

Answer (score 3):

на одном из сайтов вычитал вот это:

> Когда элемент содержит текст, который визуализируется с несколькими шрифтами, устройство вывода должно определять значение 'line-height' в соответствии с самым большим размером шрифта.

Comment: Но ведь остальные браузеры отображают это нормально.

Comment: не знаю чем это объяснить, но как раз таки Mozilla (и IE о_О) ведёт себя логично...(если просто подумать что именно Вы хотите сделать). `line-height` определяет интерлиньяж, который, в свою очередь, также определяет высоту шрифта...поэтому логично, что браузер берёт высоту самого крупного шрифта за основу, дабы не разрушать "картину". ну Вы попробуйте данный метод. мне тоже интересно - поможет или нет. никогда ещё с подобной проблемой не сталкивался.

Answer (score 0):

Элементу, который должен наследовать `line-height`, применяем свойство:

```
line-height: inherit;
```